Prompting user if they want to leave the page
I'm building a web chat with sockets, and I recently added href support for urls like so:
this is a test text measage with link
 when the users click this link i want to prompt: Are you sure you want to open this link 
but I'm not sure how to go about it

I could do document.querySelectAll("a").[...] but thats highly in inefficient 'cause new messages will be added and this has to be done every time to include all the ``.


How should I go about it?


Edit:


I'm specifying that:
I do not want to use the browsers default window.addEventListener("beforeunload"

This question is similar to: Warn user before leaving web page with unsaved changes. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

"but thats highly in inefficient" use event delegation

"I could do" - what to do exactly? You can do link.addEventListener('click', e => { if (!confirm('Go?')) e.preventDefault() }). How do you intend to process links that are opened in new tab? In such cases this results in opening a redirection page

As you add text to your chat, append it as an element (div?) so you can apply the event listener to the relevant HTMLElement.
newDiv.querySelectorAll("a")...
Better yet, use event delegation for using just 1 event handler for the container element.


var container = document.querySelector(".container")
container.addEventListener('click', function(ev) {
  if (ev.target.tagName == "A") {
    ev.preventDefault();
    var href = ev.target.href
    if (confirm("go to " + href + "?")) {
      console.log("do window.location = href here");
    }
  }
});
<div class="container">
  something with a <a href="https://example.com">link</a> that is preventDefault-ed
  <br> could have been added dynamically.
</div>



